# designing component by mdbreact

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mdbreact

I took ready-made code from the mdbreact website
And I get the error

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips on how to debug and fix this problem.

**I would love for you to help me**

**login component**

```
import React from "react";
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBInput, MDBBtn } from 'mdbreact';


export default function LoginForm() {
    return(<MDBContainer>
        <MDBRow>
            <MDBCol md="6">
                <form>
                    <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">Sign in</p>
                    <div className="grey-text">
                        <MDBInput label="Type your email" icon="envelope" group type="email" validate error="wrong"
                            success="right" />
                        <MDBInput label="Type your password" icon="lock" group type="password" validate />
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <MDBBtn>Login</MDBBtn>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </MDBCol>
        </MDBRow>
    </MDBContainer>)

}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "axois": "0.0.1-security",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "immer": "^8.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "local-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "mdbreact": "^5.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.0.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^3.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "immer": "7.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';


import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App**

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './newProject/Store/store'
import React from 'react';

import RouterApplication from './newProject/router'


function App() {
  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
       <RouterApplication></RouterApplication>
      </Provider>)
}
export default App
```

**router**

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginForm from './Component/LoginComponent/login'
import Signup from './Component/SignupComponent/signup'
import React from 'react'
export default function RouterApplication() {
    return <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/signup'>
                <Signup></Signup>
            </Route>
            <Route path='/login'>
                <LoginForm></LoginForm>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you show the App component? Is it the parent of the Login component or there are more component in the hierarchy?

Comment: hi I add the app component

Comment: There are two `import React from 'react'` in `App.js`, also please provide `./newProject/router` because that is also likely where the error could exist.

Comment: ok I add router and correct App

Comment: Please always keep `import React from 'react'` as the first line everytime (its not first import in router, App). Also line 2 and line 5 in `App` are the same and one of the reasons why that specific error shows up.

Comment: I can't see any usage of hooks somewhere. Can you reproduce the issue within a codesandbox snipper?

Comment: I fixed and still have the problem